# PPE that can withstand molten slag from arc flash

Tags: electrical-panel

I plan to get the following PPE to protect against arc flash (which my electrician experienced before).

[image]

But I found out it can't even withstand molten slag from injuring the arms. Our PPE standard or specifically 70E is only to protect chest/face from 1.2cal/cm2 arc flash.

I was told to look for chromated leather PPE or aluminum fire suits. But I couldn't find these in google. So what kind of PPE do you use to withstand splashing molten slag from arc flash category 1 or from welding, ironworks or stuff like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Arc Flash Hazard is so low in residential service both OSHA and NFPA 70E even recognize it. This question is clearly off subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be protected at the level of risk you are dealing with, I am an industrial and general journeyman. I wear a class 2 suit for most things but as suggested by ecnerwal welding gear will do a good job, BUT you still need hot gloves and a flash shield, even a solid armor suit of steel will not protect you if the flash is big enough my qualification for saying this is I have seen 2 diesel generators being paralled where the electronics failed the explosion and the flash blew through the heavy sheet metal of one of the generators leaving several hundred pounds of the copper slip rings as BB's on the floor and even damaged the concrete vault wall. So the answer should be have you done the calculations for the risk you are exposed to? If not you are can be injured, blinded, or killed by an arc flash without the proper suit. Even with the proper gear things can go bad. The clear shield can help you see what you are doing but won't protect your eyes from a large flash. I have to wear a "welding green shield" for some of the work I do and in some cases I think this almost causes accidents but if I did not have the suit and shield on that day would I still have my eyesight, 1 really bad experience in almost 40 years is enough for me to try and keep my guys safe. Even basic welding gear will stop some slag, but you need to do the calculations to know what would be needed for the work you are doing, and if having regular arc flashes that produce slag find a different line of work or contact OSHA because this is not normal.

Comment: And that... Is why I pull the main 480 switch before I do anything in the building., even putting the covers back on the 480/120 transformers.  The one time I didn't is when I found the 120/240 neutral floating at 120 above earth.  We don't have urgent production that requires work with power on, but if we did, I'd get someone like you Ed.

Answer (score 2):

Go to a welding supply, buy leathers. They will stand more abuse than most other things, but they are also a consumable, meaning you need to replace them as they become damaged in use (upside - welding leathers are usually not terribly expensive, as leather goods go.) The "cape sleeve and bib" is a good combo if you only need protection from the front, in warmer weather.

Be careful what sort / style of footwear you choose - a common error which tends to become a learning experience when cutting steel (lots of molten slag) is having footwear which does not shed incoming slag onto the floor - either because you've tucked the pants into it (don't) or because the tongue of a lace-up boot is arranged in a way that allows slag to collect and slip into the boot, following which the occupant of the boot has a strong interest in removing it as fast as possible, and different boots. Or the old "wearing fabric boots that melt" problem (or sneakers for the more foolish) or low-top shoes rather than boots.

Comment: In an arc flash, do you know how fast is the velocity of the molten slag or metal as it is projected from the melting conductor? Would the welder leather be able to withstand it (from being penetrated by it)?